# Android - Query the same order inserted in SQLite DB

Tags: android-sqlite

I am not getting the data in the same order I insert in the SQLite DB.

Create Table: SQLTable

```
  builder.append("CREATE TABLE\n").append(TABLE_NAME).append("(");

        builder.append(KEY_ROWID).append(" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,");
        for (DevicesTable col : DevicesTable.values()) {
            builder.append(col.name()).append(" ").append(col.getColumnType()).append(",");
        }

 builder.append Unique and Foreign key ....
```

When I try to execute and check the Table. I don't see the column "KEY_ROWID".

Also when I query: I don't get in the same order.

```
cursor = db.query(SQLTable.TABLE_NAME,
                    SQLTable.getColumns(),
                    SQLTable.abc.name() + "=? AND " + SQLTable.bcd.name() + " ='" + idValue + "'",
                    new String[]{String.valueOf(abcId)}, null, null, SQLTable.KEY_ROWID, null
            );
```

I tried to use the "Order By" value as KEY_ROWID. Still I don't get the sorted order.

How could I get the same order as inserted in SQLite DB.

Comment: Your code is **confusionary**. That's why **I've lost some pieces while reading it** and won't investigate any further. And that's probably why **you've lost some pieces while writing it**. Try a **more linear** approach.

Comment: yeah, I did miss.. I just added the piece of code where I create the table and the piece of code whether I use the orderBy as SQLTable.KEY_ROWID. It actually worked, after I uninstalled and installed the app. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After I uninstalled and installed the app, it worked.

When we query using OrderBy ROW_ID, it gives the same order the items were inserted in the DB.